# Авторизация yandex.music

Tags: python, post, яндекс-музыка

python 3.5, requests

Пишу скрипт для переноса плейлиста из вк в яндекс музыку. т.к. у яндекса(музыки) нет открытого API, а всё, что нашёл в интернете направлено на скачивание музыки, что можно делать без авторизации, пишу сам.
Отследил запрос на авторизацию, повторил его, результатом страница c url что-то вроде login status = ok, код ответа 200. Попробовал повторить этот запрос на сервисе онлайн пост запросов - результат такой же, но. Если после этого зайти на страницу ЯндексМузыки, то видно, что авторизация не выполнена.

Параметры и запрос:

```
data ="login=holy.walley&password=ZelenoglazoeTax1@@&twoweeks=yes&retpath=https://music.yandex.by/blocks/auth/login-status.html"
    html = requests.post('https://passport.yandex.ru/passport?mode=embeddedauth&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmusic.yandex.by%2F',data=data)
```

Возвращаемый url: https://music.yandex.by/blocks/auth/login-status.html?status=ok&ncrnd=1183

Comment: Мда, глупо вышло с паролем, уже сменил...

Comment: если запуск планируется с компьютеров,  то можно использовать selenium и подобные среды с реальным браузером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторизация не выполнена, так как вы не работаете никак с сессией и с куки.
Доки по requests
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

И вообще может вам нужно попробовать авторизоваться на яндексе через https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/

Также тут посмотрите https://toster.ru/q/22314, есть ссылка на какое то api неофициальное, можно изучить код.

Comment: Я так понимаю используя oauth я получу токен, чтобы можно было пользоваться API. Но API по Яндекс Музыке нет.
На тостере смотрел, не то.
А вот за сессию и куки спасибо. Раньше работал с Grab, и он, вроде как сам всё запоминал и т.д. , но сейчас почему-то перестал работать, может вы знаете почему? (пишет что-то вроде "превышен интервал ожидания 3000 милисекунд", естественно интернет соединение у меня работает, и страницу я гружу не большую, просто google.com .Гуглил, но через некоторое время проблема решалась сама собой, установил обнову pycharm и она снова появилась.

Comment: Я тестил ваш код, меня вообще выбрасывало на каптчу. Если превышен интервал с яндексом то может они вас уже забанили на время и даже не отвечают, после какого то времени бан снимают, если у гуглом, то ошибка где то в коде. Там на тостере есть ссылка на https://github.com/itsmepetrov/yandex-music-api. Лучше изучите их исходники. Они там как раз через oauth входят.

Answer (score 0):

Возможности создать своё oauth приложения нет, но можно воспользоваться уже созданным (официальным). Данные приложения можно подсмотреть самому сниффером или в коде неофициальной библиотеки https://github.com/MarshalX/yandex-music-api

Неполная неофициальная документация их API доступна тут: https://yandex-music.readthedocs.io/